# How to get the selected item from a 'select' tag?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

I am trying to build a custom plugin for ckeditor.

My question is that i have created a `dialog` window and it contains a '`select`' menu. I want to insert the item whatever the user
selects.

Here are my script.

```
  function customTag(editor){

      return {
          title:'Audio Link',
          minWidth : 200,
          minHeight : 200,
          buttons : [CKEDITOR.dialog.okButton, CKEDITOR.dialog.cancelButton],
          onOk: function(){
             var id = this.getContentElement('tab', 'menu').getValue();
             //not sure what to do to get item1 and item2.

          },
          contents: [
              {
                  id:'tab',
                  label: 'test',
                  elements: [
                      {
                      type:'select',
                      id:'menu',
                      items: [['item1', 0, 'item2' , 1]],
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  }

      CKEDITOR.dialog.add('customTag', function(editor){

          var ck = new customTag(editor)
          return ck;
      });
```

I am able to get value for item1 and item2 by using     `var id = this.getContentElement('tab', 'menu').getValue();` `var id` will be `0` or `1` but I also want to get `item1` and `item2` as well.

Their docs doesn't say much about how to get it.
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.html

I am not sure how to do it. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You defined select items the wrong way (see [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.select-property-items)). Anyway, use `this.getValue()` and compare it with `this.items` in `commit` method ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/JhrhF/)) to find anything you want:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'myDialog', function( editor ) {
    return {
        title: 'My Dialog',
        onOk: function() {   
            this.commitContent();
        },        
        contents: [
            {
                id: 'tab1',
                label: 'First Tab',
                title: 'First Tab',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type:'select',
                        id:'menu',
                        label: 'My select',
                        // This is the correct way of defining items.
                        items: [
                            [ 'foo', 5 ],
                            [ 'bar', 6 ]
                        ],
                        commit: function() {
                            // Combine value with items to retrieve anything you want.
                            console.log( this.getValue(), this.items );
                        }
                    }   
                ]
            }           
        ]
    };
} );
```